# Composing sentences

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, hangul

How do I compose a sentences using -아/어요, -ㅂ니다, -고 싶어요, -지 마세요 and -러 가요. Can someone please explain and show me examples? I’m really desperate

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples:

1. 저는 아침에 운동을 했**어요**.

I exercised in the morning.

2. 저는 지금 공부를 **합니다**.

I am studying (now).

3. 공부하**고 싶어요**.

I want to study.

4. 공부하**지 마세요**.

Do not study.

5. 저는 자**러 가요**.

I'm going to bed.